# Get output of echo and show it on console at the same command

Tags: bash

I have code like below:

```
a=$(echo "b")
```

And I want see output of that at the same time and also get output value to be stored to variable at one command. I am not meaning this:

```
a=$(echo "b")
echo "$a"
```

Comment: Maybe you could put something together with `read`, `tee`, and `<(...)` however, that would probably be longer and more complicated. Is there any reason (other than brevity) not to use `a=$(...); echo "$a"`?

Comment: I have get it like that because of another program syntax that I have to use on my program. Also it can be printf.

Comment: I don't understand. What other program syntax?

Comment: I have to use another code or program on my own code and I am calling it. I have reasons that i cannot show that another code to you.